# Android security vulnerability issues for PIE

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, android-security

We encountered high security risk for android PIE issues and we are developing ionic cordova based hybrid mobile app with IBM mobilefirst platform, now security scan throw the risk for as below description, please help us.

My android build sdk : 28+

In order to prevent an attacker from reliably jumping to, for example, a particular exploited function in memory, Address space layout randomization (ASLR) randomly arranges the address space positions of key data areas of a process, including the base of the executable and the positions of the stack, heap and libraries. Built with option **-pie**.

```
File : lib/mips64/libauthjni.so
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed through APAR https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PH15627

Hardly few android devices runs on mips and mips64 architecture. I suggest you to delete these lib folder and then perform security scanning.